# Can I run a travel wire back through the source conduit?

Tags: switch, conduit

I am running a 120v lighting circuit where one of the light fixtures is between the breaker box and the switch. Can I run hot, neutral and ground to the switch, then run the travel wire back through the same conduit to a junction box mid way, then run the travel wire (and the neutral and ground) to the light fixture?

Comment: Yeah. Except you don't need to run neutral to a switch when the switch is a spur/"switch loop" like that.  Since the junction boxes will be accessible forever (that's a requirement), the neutral can be easily retrofitted.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply connect the neutral and ground to the fixture as they pass its junction box, on the way to the switch location, and from the fixture to the switch location, run both the unswitched hot (unbroken at the fixture location) and a switched hot.

It's not a "traveler" (or your own special term "travel wire") unless there's a 3-way switch, and if it's going **to a fixture** it's ***still*** not a traveler - it's a **switched hot.** *Travelers* go between 3-way and 4-way (commonwealth 2-way & 3-way) switches, not to fixtures.

Comment: Thank you for the correct terminology. To be clear, there will be more switched lights on the circuit. So I can do as you say above, and also continue the neutral and ground to the switch box with the unswitched hot (that will provide power for other lights as well) and the switched hot wite? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run *switch legs* back through the same conduit as the hot.

Also in your configuration since you are using conduit if you are not installing switches that require neutrals your conduit to the switch only  needs to be sized large enough to add a neutral wire, but you do not actually need to include the neutral wire a this time.